# handling with sever side control button

Tags: asp.net

hi all i want to know that if in my login.aspx page there is two button  `login` and `cancel`

now i press enter key of my keybord by default its select cancel button  but i want to set it  on login how i will do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the defaultbutton attribute of the form:

```
<asp:Form runat="server" id="form1" defaultbutton="idofloginbutton">
...
</asp:Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<asp:Panel>` control has a `DefaultButton` property, to which you can assign the ID of a default button control.

Consider wrapping your content in a panel and assigning the `DefaultButton` property of the panel to `login`.